# In OpenGL, how to confirm a primitive is rendered properly

Tags: opengl, rendering, opengl-es

I have to confirm that a primitive (say triangle) is rendered properly in opengl.

I can use the glGetError() after a opengl draw calls(glDrawElement/glDrawArrays)

Is it enough to confirm ?
Is there any other ways to confirm?

Please let me know.

- Arun AC

Comment: What do you mean "properly"?  Are there specific types of rendering errors you're trying to detect?

Comment: You could look at the screen =)  But seriously, like Nathan is asking: what do you need to verify?  Just no GL errors, specific output compared to previous runs, what do you need to see or not see?

Comment: -If you see it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends a lot on what you mean by "properly", but overall, you pretty much can't.

Some architectures postpone actual rendering as much as possible, so if some odd error occurs at a very late stage, there's no way to signal an error. However, these cases are very, very rare, and you'll likely get an error while setting up rendering - be sure to check your shader compilation logs, etc.

A lot of things can go wrong, so it's generally a good idea to pepper your code with glerror checks. Alternatively (or additionally) you may want to hit your program with gDEBugger, or whatever AMD is calling it these days.

Now, if by "properly" you mean from a driver/hardware developer point of view, you can always just flush, read back the framebuffer and do a compare with a "golden image"..

Answer (score -1):

Well if you absolutely need NASA space mission perfection, the only way to really be sure it rendered correctly is to do it yourself in software and compare it to the OpenGL output...

That aside, if you can rely on an estimate of the number of pixels then you could investigate using [Occlusion Queries](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/occlusion_query.txt) to make a guess as to whether or not it rendered properly.